# AWS - Cannot access EC2 instance by 443 port

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm struggling with ssl configuration of my Elastic Beanstalk environment. I can reach my site by 80 port (http) but I can't reach it using 443 port. I followed this documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html but was unable to configure it properly. I'm getting 408 HTTP Status trying to reach my site (https://apploit.com). I allowed inbound traffic to port 443 for the Security Group:

[image]

and configured my load balancer to listen on port 443 and redirect traffic to port 443 on the EC2 instance:

[image]

Any ideas what is wrong with my configuration?

Comment: How many instances are there ?

Comment: @KushVyas One instance, why?

Comment: Single-instance environments don't have a load balancer and don't support HTTPS termination at the load balancer.

Comment: Please check your application logs

Answer (score 0):

Well, it works right now... don't know why, maybe it needed some time :)

Comment: Did you add any new nodes?

Answer (score -1):

As per [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html) link shared by you only in question :

> Single-instance environments don't have a load balancer and don't
>   support HTTPS termination at the load balancer.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: The poster here attached pictures of their load balancer configuration. So s/he is not in single---instance mode